# Doctronie 2 ODM MongoDB Sort in Annotations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-odm

I try to sort my query directly with annotations as it is done by ORM with MongoDB.

```php
/**
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
 */
```

I use a `@MongoDB\ReferenceMany`:

```php
class page{
  /**
   * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(
   *     targetDocument="Project\PageBundle\Document\Contenu",
   *     cascade="all",
   *     sort={"position"="ASC"}
   * )
   */
  $protected contenus;
  public function getContenus(){
      return $this->contenus;
  }
}
```

When I make a `$page->getContenus();` call the MongoDB query is working but the listing is not sorted. I cleared the cache but it doesn't help.

What can I do?

Comment: I am try with sort={"position"=1} and i have the same problem

Comment: Try adding the `mappedBy` property to the reference annotation. Where it points to the property in your `Contenu` class that stores the ref to the `Page`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jamie Sutherland it's work. I should to add mappedBy.